# Error in inherits(data, "data.frame") : argument "data" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I am keep running into the error and I can't seem to find any apperant problem in the code.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
require(data.table)


library(ggplot2)
require(data.table)

data <- as.data.frame(fread("MyND_merged.tsv"))

g <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = study, y = value)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    facet_wrap(facets = ~type, scale ='free') +
    ggpubr::compare_means()
```

The error says

```
Error in inherits(data, "data.frame") : 
  argument "data" is missing, with no default
```

`data` is defined in the code, I believe so - would someone please help me solving this error?
Thank you

```
> str(data)
'data.frame':   4266 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ V1      : int  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
 $ sample  : chr  "AANDS0002-01"  "AANDS0002-01" ...
 $ type    : chr  "index1" "index 2" ...
 $ value   : num  0.0122 0.9729  ...
 $ donor_id: chr  "AANDS0002" "AANDS0002"  ...
 $ gender  : chr  "M" "M" "M" "M" ...
 $ age     : int  80 80 80 80 80 80 75 75 75 75 ...
 $ disease : chr  "name1" "name2" ...
 $ study   : chr  "mynd_2" "mynd_2" "mynd_2" "mynd_2" ...
```

Comment: What do you get if you just do `fread("MyND_merged.tsv")`? Have you confirmed this actually returns some data?

Comment: http://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/reference/compare_means.html this suggests that `ggpubr::compare_means()` is not used in a plot, and is possibly throwing the missing data error.

Comment: The  fread function has no problem, the data is read. str(data) is attached to the question.

Comment: ah, I see, so. I should found another way to do compare_means()?

Comment: You probably were looking for `ggpubr::stat_compare_means()`, `compare_means()` just prints a table with statistics, and doesn't do anything related to plotting. It's pretty clearly explained in the help files what the functions do.